# Entity Framework automatic relation linking is not working in .net Core 3.0

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core-3.0

```
 public class tbl_User
    {
        [Key]
        public int userId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Branch")]
        public int masterbranchId { get; set; }
        //[ForeignKey("masterbranchId")]
        public virtual tbl_MasterBranch MasterBranch { get; set; }
}
```

This is the class and there is another class for tbl_MasterBranch . When we return users link MasterBranch is null. This was worked fine in MVC5.

Answer (score 1):

You're currently (and the MVC5 app was formerly) relying on lazy loading. A key difference in EF Core is that lazy loading must be explicitly enabled via:

```
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(o =>
    o.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default"))
     .UseLazyLoadingProxies());
```

However, you should really avoid lazy loading. For the convenience it may add, there's a ton of potential pitfalls that can severely impact your application performance and hammer you database. If you want related entities included, it's best to eagerly load them when querying:

```
var users = await _context.Users.Include(x => x.MasterBranch).ToListAsync();
```